# How do I bold cells in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Using openpyxl in Python. I'm attempting to parse through 7 worksheets and assign them all a frozen header that's bolded. I've tested and the header is frozen and all the cell values are how I want them to be, but I keep getting the error:

NameError: name 'Font' is not defined

I'm attempting two different ways. One to bold the entire row, another to bold each individual cell, but neither will work for me.

I'm on openpyxl version 3.0.10, which I believe is the most current. Here is the code in question.

```
for ws in wb:
    print("Now in sheet: " + ws.title)
    ws['A1'].value = "Name"
    ws['B1'].value = "Client Name"
    ws['C1'].value = "Project Title"
    ws['D1'].value = "Actual Hours"
    ws['E1'].value = "Date"
    ws['F1'].value = "Notes"
    myRow = ws.row_dimensions[1]
    myRow.font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['A1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['B1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['C1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['D1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['E1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    # ws['F1'].font = Font(bold=True)
    ws.freeze_panes = ws['A2']
```

It should be noted, I'm very new to python, but I believe I have the syntax set up correctly.

Comment: You need to import the `Font()` class first - `from openpyxl.styles import Font`.

Comment: @MattDMo That did it. I have import openpyxl already, so I assumed that would be all that was needed, but I guess I needed that specific import statement as well. Thanks!